# When does applinks get verified for existing users?

Tags: android, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

We have app links set up in our app. But the dynamic links, on tap, ask to select between [browser, MyApp]. It should open the app directly without asking the user to choose.
We found that `assetlinks.json` did not contain correct SHA-256.

We have updated it and reinstalling the app from playstore works fine for us, that opens the app immediately after tapping on the dynamic link. But we are unable to find out when our existing users will see the effect.

Will applinks get verified when they update their app from the store in future?
Or, are there any other methods of triggering app links verification?